# Compare two sets of Ranges and MsgBox amount and value of common cell values

Tags: excel, compare, range, msgbox, vba

I have a problem with this code and I'm not able to resolve it.

I have two sets of ranges; Range("C14:C19") and Range("E14:E19") each containing 6 Numbers generated randomly (I already coded the random selection).

My goal is to, after generating the Numbers, compare both Ranges.
If both Ranges contain identical Numbers,
I want to MsgBox the amount of identical Numbers found in both Ranges and also the value of each Numbers.

**Example**: 
After generating the Numbers, if both Ranges have the values 9 and 7 in common, the MsgBox would look like:

There is/are 2 number(s) in the winning combination and it's/there value(s) is/are : 7, 9

Here Is what I was able to do up to now.

```
Private Sub Compare()

    Dim rgnChoix As Range, rgnTirage As Range, i As Range, j As Range, iVal As Integer

    Set rgnChoix = Range("C14:C19")
    Set rgnTirage = Range("E14:E19")

        For Each i In rgnChoix.Cells

            For Each j In rgnTirage.Cells

                If i.value = j.value Then

                    MsgBox "There is/are" & " " & iVal & " " & "number(s) in the winning combination and it's/there value(s) is/are :" & " " & i.value, , "Erika"
                        Exit Sub

                 End If
             Next j
          Next i

  iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C14:C19"),"i.value=j.value")

End Sub
```

Thanks!!
Erika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work as you wish. But if same number occurs more than once in a range it counts it as a seperate match. It counts all the matchs seperately. If one range includes two 4 and the other includes three 4 it counts six matching.

```
Private Sub Compare()
    Dim rgnChoix As Range, rgnTirage As Range, i As Range, j As Range, iVal As Integer, sVal As String
    Set rgnChoix = Range("C14:C19")
    Set rgnTirage = Range("E14:E19")
    For Each i In rgnChoix.Cells
        For Each j In rgnTirage.Cells
            If i.Value = j.Value Then
                iVal = iVal + 1
                sVal = sVal & "," & CStr(i.Value)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    sVal = Mid(sVal, 2)
    MsgBox "There is/are" & " " & iVal & " " & "number(s) in the winning combination and it's/there value(s) is/are :" & " " & sVal, , "Erika"
End Sub
```